# Binomial Distribution With Scale Variable?

Tags: probability, random-generation, distributions

I'm attempting to generate some random data using a distribution. I need each random point to fall within a certain range e.g. 0-20, and I would also like to control where the center of the curve lies. For this the Binomial distribution was perfect. Later on I realized I would also like to set the scale for the curve, but the binomial distribution cannot do this. Is there some other distribution that could give me control over all three variables? I apologize if I don't use the correct terminology, I'm not a statistician, so please correct me if there is a way I can be more clear.

Edited as per Glen_b's suggestion:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The first two images are of binomial distribution. The distribution is bounded by the number of trials, which acts as a range for the data. I can also control the mode by altering the probability. The third image is of a normal distribution. It shows that modifying the σ variable will increase/decrease the scale of the distribution. What I would like is a distribution which gives control of all three variables: the location of the mode, the scale of the distribution, and a range.

Comment: You want to generate integer data points?

Comment: Yes that would be fine.

Comment: "That would be fine" is inadequate as a response; for example it doesn't indicate if *non* integers are okay. What do you *need*? Perhaps you could also draw a picture for what you are trying to achieve above what you can do with the binomial.

Comment: Thanks Glen, I've added some more information. Also, I meant that integers would work as well as non-integers, but I suppose they would actually work best for my purposes.

Comment: You could try with a beta-binomial distribution, but that can only give larger variance than the binomial, not smaller.